# unexpected ; but i cant see why

Tags: php

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/realcas/public_html/eshop/ecms/system/classes/database.php on line 29

This is the code on line 29

```
return empty($resultArray) ? "Error in Query " ? json_encode($resultArray);
```

this is the section of code that is the issue

```
public function select($table,$options,$where,$orderby)
{
    $options = empty($options) ? "*"   : $options;
    $where  =  empty($where)   ? "1=1" : $where;
    $orderby = empty($orderby) ? ""    : $orderby;

    $qry = "SELECT $options FROM $table WHERE $where $orderby ";
    $result = mysql_query($qry) or die(json_encode(array("error",mysql_error())));

    while(($resultArray[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)));
    return empty($resultArray) ? "Error in Query " ? json_encode($resultArray);

    return json_encode($resultArray);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want probably this one

```
return empty($resultArray) ? "Error in Query " : json_encode($resultArray);
```

because its

```
($condition) ? "condition is true" : "condition is false";
```

I see you're using it already, so I assume it was just a typo

Also remove this line

```
    return json_encode($resultArray);
```

because it's unnecessary and never will happen. Additionally I'm not sure that your while loop is correct.

**Result**

```
public function select($table,$options,$where,$orderby)
{
    $options = empty($options) ? "*"   : $options;
    $where  =  empty($where)   ? "1=1" : $where;
    $orderby = empty($orderby) ? ""    : $orderby;

    $qry = "SELECT $options FROM $table WHERE $where $orderby ";
    $result = mysql_query($qry) or die(json_encode(array("error",mysql_error())));

    while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))){ $resultArray[] = $row; }
    return count($resultArray) < 1 ? "Error in Query " : json_encode($resultArray);
}
```

Comment: K, thanks. I did that but when I ran a test to see if it would show there was an error (ie: not in Table) all it shows is a blank screen

Comment: @RussellHarrower: sure it won't, if you expect json, you can't give browser "Erorr in Query" text

Comment: Well I know I can do the following json_encode(array("error","not in table") and that is what I want to show if it is not in the table? Is tehre anyway to do this?

Comment: @RussellHarrower: take a look at my updated (last) row of code. You might want count() instead

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you don't need the last `return` statement, that's already covered by the previous ternary op.

Secondly, the other `return` should look like this:

```
return empty($resultArray) ? "Error in Query " : json_encode($resultArray);
```